# Does the product between two plus-minus signs yield a minus-plus sign?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

While studying the Complex Algebra section of Weber & Arfken's Mathematical Methods for Physicists, I've stumbled upon the following expression, concerning the solutions $y_{1,2}=-1\pm i \sqrt3 $ for $y(x)=0$,  $y(x)=x^2 +x + 1$,
$$\left[\frac 12  (-1 \pm i \sqrt{3})\right]^2+\frac 12(-1 \pm i \sqrt{3}) +1 = 
\frac 14 (1 -3  \mp 2i \sqrt3 -2 \pm 2i \sqrt3  ) +1 =0$$

I can't see clearly why the $\pm$ sign in the first brackets turns into $\mp$ after being squared, and I thought this question would fit better here than in the Physics forum. My book's edition is the 2004 international version, if needed.

Comment: coz you are multiplying (-1) with $\pm \sqrt {3}$. Multiplication with minus changes sign

Answer (score 4):

Let's suppose $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers
$$(a\pm b)^2=a^2\pm2ab+b^2$$
Then replace $a$ with $-a$:
$$(-a\pm b)^2=(-a)^2\pm 2(-a)b+b^2=a^2\mp 2ab+b^2$$

Answer (score 3):

From the basic $(x + y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2$ expansion, the $\pm$ is turned into $\mp$ after being squared due to the product of two times the first term in $(-1 \pm i\sqrt{3})$, which is $-1$, times the third term, i.e., $\pm i\sqrt{3}$, to get the middle term of the expansion, i.e.,

$$2(-1)(\pm i\sqrt{3}) = \mp2i\sqrt{3} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$